# 400 Bad Request While Using `django.test.client`

Tags: python, django, testing, django-rest-framework

I believe I am missing a fundamental setup.

I'm trying to test my API using Django's testing framework.

From the shell, I try:

```
from django.test import Client
c = Client()
r = c.get('/')
```

I get a `400 Bad Request`, which is not the expected output.

Using a simple `curl` from the command line:

```
curl http://localhost
```

I get the expected output: `{"detail":"Authentication credentials...`

Am I missing something basic?

Comment: What exactly is you question/problem here?

Comment: `test.Client` was returning an unexpected value, `400 Bad Request`. It should have been returning json from my API. I wasn't sure what I had wrong in my setup. It looks like I just had the `DEBUG` flag set incorrectly (see my answer below).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use the test client while DEBUG is False, you just need to add 'testserver' into your ALLOWED_HOSTS setting

Comment: I kept getting the error in question even with `DEBUG=True` for some reason. Adding `'testserver'` fixed it. If somebody could explain why is that so, I'd be grateful (tests were running fine with `manage.py test`, the problem persisted only in `shell`)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like:

```
DEBUG = True
```

is needed in the `settings.py` file for this to work.

Comment: I'll leave this answer unaccepted for a couple of days in case something better comes along.